# How to configure keycloak behind two reverse proxies?

Tags: java, apache, reverse-proxy, keycloak

I have a problem concerning Apache used as a reverse proxy and Keycloak.
Besides my reverse proxy there's another reverse proxy which is used by the applied by the customer.

I want to log in to Keycloak's admin console.
Trying to do this locally works as expected: http://localhost/application1/auth/admin/
The login form is shown and I can log in successfully.

But trying to log in from the external URL does not work:
https://externalurl.com/application1/auth/admin/

The login form is shown, I submit the form and the (empty) form is displayed again.
The cookies AUTH_SESSION_ID, KC_RESTART, KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY and KEYCLOAK_SESSION are set correctly.

The view in Apache's access.log shows the following:
(local and working call)

```
10.1.7.192 - - [29/May/2019:11:16:27 +0200] "GET /auth/admin/master/console HTTP/1.1" 302 -
10.1.7.192 - - [29/May/2019:11:16:28 +0200] "GET /auth/admin/master/console/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8198
10.1.7.192 - - [29/May/2019:11:16:29 +0200] "GET /auth/admin/master/console/config HTTP/1.1" 200 195
10.1.7.192 - - [29/May/2019:11:16:29 +0200] "GET /auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=security-admin-console&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexternalurl.com%2Fapplication1%2Fauth%2Fadmin%2Fmaster%2Fconsole%2F&state=cef5a6cb-4327-45e7-8e97-0b3e74a27ea6&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=35edfb09-a16a-41dc-83d6-453393e61391 HTTP/1.1" 200 3120
10.1.7.192 - - [29/May/2019:11:16:33 +0200] "POST /auth/realms/master/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=5iqyNYW56tGETAGGHLEp54m5JbEXU4us-kDe1S1k10Q&execution=ee5e5166-6dcf-47d1-a130-521aaedfd08d&client_id=security-admin-console&tab_id=VF8WaW2--uM HTTP/1.1" 302 -
10.1.7.192 - - [29/May/2019:11:16:33 +0200] "GET /auth/admin/master/console/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8198
10.1.7.192 - - [29/May/2019:11:16:33 +0200] "GET /auth/admin/master/console/config HTTP/1.1" 200 195
--- differences start here
10.1.7.192 - - [29/May/2019:11:16:33 +0200] "GET /auth/admin/master/console/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8198
10.1.7.192 - - [29/May/2019:11:16:33 +0200] "GET /auth/admin/master/console/config HTTP/1.1" 200 195
10.1.7.192 - - [29/May/2019:11:16:33 +0200] "GET /auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=security-admin-console&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexternalurl.com%2Fapplication1%2Fauth%2Fadmin%2Fmaster%2Fconsole%2F&state=8931d4e0-d9b6-41fc-92ef-1e937d5c7704&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=fedd80bb-a5e0-4ea1-ad6e-77a8ab0b9938 HTTP/1.1" 200 3120
```

But trying from external client I get this message:

```
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:14:54 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/master/console HTTP/1.1" 302 -
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:14:55 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/master/console/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8198
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:14:55 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/master/console/config HTTP/1.1" 200 183
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:14:55 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=security-admin-console&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fapplication1%2Fauth%2Fadmin%2Fmaster%2Fconsole%2F&state=6815eac5-5809-4965-a802-b6ba9479a8d8&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=852c3a37-90ed-4bdc-a9dd-50c4ec1291aa HTTP/1.1" 200 3108
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:02 +0200] "POST /application1/auth/realms/master/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=Ehw_zcZmjJruVvIJiajTLqBbN49M7wbsRSoCi24y8MQ&execution=ee5e5166-6dcf-47d1-a130-521aaedfd08d&client_id=security-admin-console&tab_id=qV6HNXsVgtU HTTP/1.1" 302 -
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:02 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/master/console/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8198
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:02 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/master/console/config HTTP/1.1" 200 183
--- differences start here
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:03 +0200] "POST /application1/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1" 200 3102
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:03 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/master/console/messages.json?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 116906
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:03 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/master/console/whoami HTTP/1.1" 200 443
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:03 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html/init?client_id=security-admin-console&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost HTTP/1.1" 204 -
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:03 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/serverinfo HTTP/1.1" 200 142210
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:03 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/realms HTTP/1.1" 200 3113
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:04 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/realms/master HTTP/1.1" 200 3111
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:04 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/realms HTTP/1.1" 200 3113
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:04 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/realms HTTP/1.1" 200 3113
::1 - - [29/May/2019:11:15:04 +0200] "GET /application1/auth/admin/realms HTTP/1.1" 200 3113
```

Of course Keycloak's standalone.xml is set to:

```
<web-context>application1/auth</web-context>
```

and

```
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true" proxy-address-forwarding="true"/>
```

Finally the relevant part of my apache configuration:

```
DumpIOInput On
DumpIOOutput On
LogLevel debug
ForensicLog logs/forensic.txt

ProxyPreserveHost Off
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For

LogLevel debug

<LocationMatch "^/(application1/auth)/*">
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8180
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8180
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/(auth)/*">
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8180/application1
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8180/application1
</LocationMatch>

###This reads the value of X-ORIG-HOST into TempValue
SetEnvIf X-ORIG-HOST ".+" TempValue=$0
###This will overwrite the value of "Host" if it was already set
RequestHeader set Host %{TempValue}e env=TempValue

ProxyPassReverseCookiePath "/application1/" "/"
```

Can someone help me or give me a hint where to look next?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem with one ssl reverse proxy (haproxy) on top of a nginx proxypassing to keycloak. Got a white page instead of the admin console. Apparently this is due to refreshpermissions js function requesting whoami api on keycloak and getting a 401. Tried about everything with x-forwarded headers without success.

Comment: I think this is due to the stickiness config in your ALB (if you're using one). Just configure your target group to have duration-based stickiness.

Comment: for us worked after we removed this header: `RequestHeader unset Authorization`